# Как получить в коде (C++) название видеокарты, к которой подключен монитор

Tags: c++, linux, драйвер, monitor

Как можно получить название видеокарты в коде на линуксе, к которой подключен монитор.
Хотелось бы пробежаться по всем мониторам подключенным к компу, и получить от каждого название видеокарты, к которой они подключены.

Comment: Воспользоваться какой-нибудь либой. Было бы только желание найти её...

Comment: А если видеокарт несколько и к каждой подключен монитор или телевизор?

Comment: добавь немного конкретики — какая цель у этого... в текущей формулировке посоветовать что-то конкретное может быть довольно сложно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Хотелось бы пробежаться по всем мониторам подключенным к компу, и получить от каждого название видеокарты, к которой они подключены. То есть мы могли учитывать и то, что писал выше Croessmah.

Comment: @Mitski_fys, гм... вообще говоря, до запуска иксов сложно определить, что такое «монитор». Можно определить fb'шные и drm'ные адаптеры, но как-либо запросить, есть ли у них какие-то мониторы не всегда возможно, а когда возможно, например, через `edid`, то для этого требуется, как минимум root... От самого X-сервера это узнать тоже проблематично — я не нашёл ни какого API, чтобы запросить его структуру... самое простое, что можно сделать — запросить имя устройства от glx, но что оно покажет в случае когда один сервер работает сразу на нескольких устройствах — хз... в общем всё сложно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer На самом деле я кажется нашел нечто мне нужное, если выполнить команду xprop -root, то под значением _GNOME_SESSION_RENDERER(STRING) мы получим как раз то, что хочется узнать, но не тестил еще то, как этот параметр будет себя всти, если подключить к разным видеокартам. Поэтому, если все получится, то отвечу на свой вопрос.

Comment: запустил у себя - ничего полезного для задачи не показывает. Правда у меня xfce+gentoo

Comment: @Mitski_fys, само собой, это свойство будет только под гномом установлено (а скорее даже только под третьегномом), так что на его наличие полагаться явно не следует... да и на практике это скорей всего тот же самый glx'овый рендерер, о котором я говорил выше со всеми вытекающими ограничениями...

Comment: ещё есть `xrandr --query`, который выдает очень много интересной информации. Правда я тут подумал, вот у меня primus на nvidia и один и тот же монитор может быть подключен к разным (или к двум одновременно?) видеокартам

Comment: @KoVadim, ты хотел сказать *optimus*?

Comment: у меня это примус:) потому что бамблби.